# I can' t use Image to Base64 String function

Tags: c#, image, sockets, client-server, base64

I'm making multi client chat server(done).

but I want to add image send.
I used this method when sending a message
client1 write message and getbyte -> Server -> getstring

So I'm coding like this (I can't this part)
load image -> ImageToBase64(image) -> getbyte --> server --> getstring-> Base64ToImage 
Client Send part

how can i use this function and this method can be run.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Image screen;
    screen=Image.FromFile("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Paint.bmp");
    screentext = ImageToBase64(screen); //actually I do not know what parameter should be here

    StreamWriter wrthr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\giden.txt");
    wrthr.Write(screentext); 
    wrthr.Close(); // result empty txt
    }




public string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
  }
}


public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
  // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, 
    imageBytes.Length);

  // Convert byte[] to Image
  ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
  Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
  return image;
}
```

Comment: i can't get your question. State it clearly

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: how can i use ImageToBase64 function  i dont know second parameter and this method can be run (load image -> ImageToBase64(image) -> getbyte --> server --> getstring-> Base64ToImage)

Comment: Side-note: your writing code should either use a `using` statement, or just use `File.WriteAllText`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: There are two problems here...

### Picking a second argument to `ImageToBase64`

It's up to you - do you want to keep it as a BMP file? If so, you don't really need to go via an `Image` at all... just load the bytes from `Paint.bmp`, and convert them directly into Base64:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Paint.bmp");
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\giden.txt",
                  Convert.ToBase64String(bytes));
```

Or you may wish to choose a different format, e.g. PNG or JPEG, e.g.

```
string screentext = ImageToBase64(screen, ImageFormat.Png);
```

(It's not clear where `screentext` is declared at the moment, but it should almost certainly be a local variable.)

### Converting from base64...

This is the problem:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, 
  imageBytes.Length);

// Convert byte[] to Image
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
```

You don't need the `Write` call, and it's actively *harmful* here:

- You've constructed the `MemoryStream` with `imageBytes`, so it already contains that data
- By writing to the stream, you've moved the "cursor" to the end... so there's nothing to read

Just use:

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
  // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
  return Image.FromStream(ms, true);
}
```